# download bitcoin core safely: wrong checksum

Tags: bitcoin-core, sha256, checksum

I've downloaded the "classic" linux bitcoin core 0.19.1 (tgz) on https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/

In the SHA file that's on the website this is the key:

> 5fcac9416e486d4960e1a946145566350ca670f9aaba99de6542080851122e4c  bitcoin-0.19.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz

In my terminal, when I do sha256sum filename, I don't get this key.

Also when I run this I get a [FAILED]

> sha256sum --ignore-missing --check SHA256SUMS.asc

1) Am I doing this right ?
2) if yes does it mean bitcoincore.org compromised ?

Comment: What size is your file?  It should be 31995432 bytes.  When I downloaded it just now, I got the correct checksum, so I would wonder if your download was truncated or otherwise corrupted.

Comment: same amount of bytes. I extracted it to test it works

Comment: could you try using sha256sum without the check flag and compare the hashes manually? maybe there was a problem with the `asc` file download.